# "Fast link detected" warning in GP management console

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012

There is a message that is shown in every report i make in Group Policy Results section of Group Policy Management Console, saying that "A fast link is detected". I followed the link in the waring, but after I read the page several times, I concluded, that I can ignore the warning.

However, I noticed that the group policies are not applied when security filtering is used untl "gpupdate /sync" is executed...

Is this related to the fast sync?

In general, can somebody explain me the consequences of fast links briefly?

Comment: Could be notifying you that it's fast but not gigabit: i.e. 100Mbps Fast Ethernet. This may or may not be enough to do whatever it needs to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing. It looks like it is just notifying you that the connection to this computer shows as a fast link, as opposed to a slow link detected. This is important if you have GPO's that are implementing on machines that are located in different regions.

Hope this helps